# Run tests in parallel using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to parallelize the execution of tests on 2 or more devices.

I have a list with tests, and I want to distribute them across all devices in the `test_proc` function. For example, `test1.py` to the first device, `test2.py` to the second and etc. They are executed in parallel,
If `test1.py` was executed faster, then `test3.py` went to the first device, etc. under the list with tests.
I created a queue with tests, and now I have that:
If `test1.py` runs faster than `test2.py`, `test3.py` is not running on the first device, but waiting for `test2.py` to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the multiprocessing.Queue [as described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#examples) which will fix this. It creates a shared queue between the processes and then each process will pull from it as they finish the task before.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker(input):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = func(*args)
        # do something

def test1():
    pass
def test2():
    pass
def test3():
    pass

functions = [test1, test2, test3]

tests = Queue()

def test_proc(functions, tests):
    all_process = []
    for x in functions:   # functions would be list of tests you want to run
        tests.put(x)
    for i in number_of_processes:   # start up a number of processes 
        process = Process(target=worker, args=(tests))
        all_process.append(process)
        process.start()
    for p in all_process:
        tests.put('STOP')   # stop each process via the queue
        p.join()

if name == "__main__":
    test_proc(functions, tests)
```

Comment: I don't see where in this code dev , in test_proc i mean

Comment: I took your example and made it more generic so that you could implement what you needed. test1, test2, test3 would be replaced with the logic necessary for your functions to run. Since I don't know what your `devs` is doing, I didn't include it or some of your other code like the is_active because I don't know what it's doing to implement it properly.  If you want to iterate on the devs instead of the functions, as in each function is the same but devs is different, it would need to change a bit. Add to queue the devs instead of the functions, and have workers do all logic.

Comment: is_active checks device free or not, device - remote machines, where tests run. In function test i am rewriting config file - change host and ip of devices

Comment: For devices can i write like that?

Comment: You don’t need to do that. Each process will keep itself busy and gather the next task on its own. That is what the queue is for. You set the processes you want and the processes will then pull from queue for tasks. If you are wanting to run the tests on other devices, multiprocessing is not doing that for you. Multiprocessing uses multiple cores from the machine you run it on.